# Remover valor "cabeçalho" json

Tags: php, angularjs

Estou com um problema para gerar um json em php, após a consulta ele me retorna isso

```
{"37":{"codigo":"37","firstname":"Aluno","lastname":"Toledo","atividade":"A","checklist":null},
"1475":{"codigo":"1475","firstname":"Alzira","lastname":" Cabral","atividade":"A","checklist":"C"}}
```

tem como eu remover o "37" e o "1475"??

porque quero resolver esse problema, quando chamo ele em um http.get pelo angular, ele está ordenando por esse "cabeçalho" do json...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$array = json_decode('{"37":{"codigo":"37","firstname":"Aluno","lastname":"Toledo","atividade":"A","checklist":null},
                       "1475":{"codigo":"1475","firstname":"Alzira","lastname":" Cabral","atividade":"A","checklist":"C"}}', 1);

$result = array();   

foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
{
    $result[] = $value;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo, perfeito!

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = json_decode('{"37":{"codigo":"37","firstname":"Aluno","lastname":"Toledo","atividade":"A","checklist":null},"1475":{"codigo":"1475","firstname":"Alzira","lastname":" Cabral","atividade":"A","checklist":"C"}}');

$array_without_keys = array_values($array);

echo json_encode($array_whitout_keys);
```

Comment: está retornando null